# How to move marker with animation along routing path?

Tags: web, leaflet, frontend, openstreetmap, leaflet.draw

I want to move marker along curved path.I do receive LatLong every minute.
for example A, B are received LatLong locations. I need right way to make it happen.
I could move using [leaflet.animateMarker](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker)

but it moves from A point to B which is bad when the path is curved.
[curved path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tuO9.png). Please advise if you have any idea about how to move the marker along curved path? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lib from GitHub [This](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker). It is very commonly used to animate markers on Leaflet map. Hope this will cover your needs.

Features

- Let move your markers along a polyline.
- You can zoom in/out, your moving marker will be at the right place !
- You can pause or end the animation whenever you want.
- You can deal with events.
- You can make loop.
- You can add the the point one by one.
- You can add station at some points of the polyline.

Comment: Yes you true but it moves from A point to B which is bad when the path is curved.  I want to move along curved route. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tuO9.png)